# Treeview expand event. Как создать слушатель на раскрытие списка?

Tags: java, javafx, treeview, listener

Добрый день. Есть Treeview с 2-мя уровнями вложенности. Нужно добавить 3-ий уровень, но тогда в сумме получится очень большое количество объектов, плюс с ними надо еще и оперировать. Решил заполнять дерево динамически по раскрытию 2-го уровня из базы данных.

Проблема в том, что я не понимаю как получить событие для элемента 2-го уровня. Нашел пример:

```
treeItem.expandedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
@Override
public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
    System.out.println("newValue = " + newValue);
    BooleanProperty bb = (BooleanProperty) observable;
    System.out.println("bb.getBean() = " + bb.getBean());
    TreeItem t = (TreeItem) bb.getBean();
    // Do whatever with t
}
});
```

Но в этом примере слушатель добавляется на элемент TreeItem. Соответственно встает вопрос: А как из списка в 2000 TreeItem'ов получить ссылку на нужный, если клик на них не совершается, а только нажимается соответствующий "треугольник" раскрытия?

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: На каждый трееайтем вешать лисенер, и смотреть, если он раскрывается ( if (newValue) ), то делать создавать новый айтем, и на этот новый айтем вешать лисенер. Так не подходит?

Comment: Так вот именно реализация в коде данного способа мне не понятна.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем спасибо еще раз за подсказки [Andrew Bystrov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177093/andrew-bystrov).
Суть решения свелась к следующему:

```
for (TreeItem t:treeList){
        if (twAllProd.getTreeItemLevel(t)==2){
            t.expandedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
                    System.out.println("newValue = " + newValue);
                    BooleanProperty bb = (BooleanProperty) observable;
                    System.out.println("bb.getBean() = " + bb.getBean());
                    TreeItem t = (TreeItem) bb.getBean();
                        if (t.isExpanded()){                                                                //String id = categoryData.get(treeList.indexOf(t)).getProductCategoryId();
                            String query = "SELECT * from keaz_products WHERE product_category_id = "
                                    + categoryData.get(treeList.indexOf(t)).getProductCategoryId();
                            try {
                                productData = dbw.selectWorks(query,"Product");
                                t.getChildren().clear();
                                for (Product p : productData){

                                    t.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<String>(p.getTitle()));
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        } else if (!t.isExpanded()){
                            t.getChildren().clear();
                            t.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>(""));
                        }
                    // Do whatever with t
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Через цикл добавил слушатель на каждый элемент, и потом в соответствии с раскрытием/закрытием элементы добавляются/удаляются.

Answer (score 1):

```
ChangeListener<Boolean> listener = new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
        BooleanProperty bb = (BooleanProperty) observable;
        TreeItem t = (TreeItem) bb.getBean();
        if (newValue) {
            t.expandedProperty().addListener(listener)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Использовал ваш пример, однако почему-то не работает.